# How to protect ms access front end from increasing sizes

Tags: vba, ms-access

this time i need everyone's help to resolve this issue.
I have one splited database and front end and it's used by 150 users. My problem is when the users updating through front end its size is keep on increasing and the back end is increasing slowly. So it's creating latency. I'm connected the backend through  linked tables. Please suggest a solution to reduce the size of front end. If I'm doing a compact then its working perfectly.

Comment: Keep doing a compact.

Comment: Doing compact all the time is the only solution?

Comment: Set Auto Compact on close - `Application.SetOption "Auto Compact", True`

Comment: yes, as far as i know. simplest way. there are ways to do it every so often, not every use, which is probably what you want to look into.

Comment: Boss -Nagaraj, if we are using auto comapct on close then it's showing one error while opening the front end by another user. Like this is opened by admin ~~ db location ~~ computer name ~~.

Comment: Every user should have their own local copy of the frontend.

Comment: hi thanks for the help ever one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a Compact on Close anytime you close the DB.  It's super-easy; just check the box@  As I know, there really isn't a specific time to perform a C/R, but a regular schedule is good thing to set up, whether it be once a day, once a week, or once a month.

Here is a jazzed-up version of the compact on close, which you can run on a regular basis, using Windows Task Scheduler.  You are basically controlling one DB from another DB.  I used to run these processes overnight at a former consulting job I had.  It worked fine for more than 1 year.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'   Declare an enumeration of long integer
'   constants, to be used as the return values
'   for the RepairDatabase() function.
'   As Access's CompactRepair() method returns
'   TRUE or FALSE, the Enum uses -1 (TRUE) for
'   success and 0 for failure.
Public Enum ryCompactResult
    cmpCompactSuccessful = -1
    cmpCompactFailed = 0
    cmpErrorOccurred = 1
    cmpSourceFileDoesNotExist = 2
    cmpInvalidSourceFileNameExtension = 3
    cmpDestinationFileExists = 4
End Enum


Private Sub TestRepair()

    Dim strSource As String
    Dim strDestination As String
    Dim lngRetVal As ryCompactResult

    strSource = "C:\MyFolder\db1.mdb"
    strDestination = "C:\MyFolder\db2.mdb"

    '   Call the function:
    lngRetVal = RepairDatabase(strSource, strDestination)

    '   Examine the return value from the function
    '   and display appropriate message:
    Select Case lngRetVal

    Case cmpCompactSuccessful
        MsgBox "Compact & repair successful.", _
            vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
            "Program Information"

    Case cmpSourceFileDoesNotExist
        MsgBox strSource & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "The above file does not exist.", _
            vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, _
            "Program Finished"

    Case cmpInvalidSourceFileNameExtension
        MsgBox strSource & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "The above file has an invalid filename " _
            & "extension.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, _
            "Program Finished"

    Case cmpDestinationFileExists
        MsgBox strDestination & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "The above destination file exists. " _
            & vbNewLine _
            & "Please delete the above file or " _
            & "use a different destination filename.", _
            vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Program Finished"

    Case cmpErrorOccurred
        '   The RepairDatabase() function has
        '   already displayed an error message.

    End Select


End Sub

Function RepairDatabase( _
    strSource As String, _
    strDestination As String) As ryCompactResult

    ' IN:
    '
    '   strSource:
    '       The full path to the database that is
    '       to be compacted.
    '
    '   strDestination:
    '       The full path to the resultant database
    '       after strSource has been compacted.
    '
    ' OUT:
    '
    '   This function returns one of the values in
    '   the ryCompactResult Enum.


    Dim lngRetVal As ryCompactResult
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFileNameExtn As String
    Dim lngPos As Long


On Error GoTo Error_RepairDatabase

    '   See if source file exists:
    strFileName = Dir(strSource)
    If Len(strFileName) = 0 Then
        lngRetVal = cmpSourceFileDoesNotExist
        GoTo Exit_RepairDatabase
    End If

    '   See if source filename has appropriate
    '   filename extension (mdb or accdb).
    '   First, see if filename contains a period:
    lngPos = InStr(strFileName, ".")
    If lngPos = 0 Then
        '   Period not found in filename;
        '   i.e. no filename extension found.
        lngRetVal = cmpInvalidSourceFileNameExtension
        GoTo Exit_RepairDatabase
    Else
        '   Get filename extension:
        strFileNameExtn = Mid(strFileName, lngPos + 1)
        strFileNameExtn = LCase(strFileNameExtn)

        Select Case strFileNameExtn
        Case "mdb", "accdb"
            '   Correct filename extension found.
            '   We can proceed with compact & repair.
        Case Else
            '   Invalid filename extension found.
            lngRetVal = cmpInvalidSourceFileNameExtension
            GoTo Exit_RepairDatabase
        End Select
    End If

    '   Destination file must not exist:
    strFileName = Dir(strDestination)
    If Len(strFileName) > 0 Then
        lngRetVal = cmpDestinationFileExists
        GoTo Exit_RepairDatabase
    End If

    '   Compact and repair database:
    lngRetVal = Application.CompactRepair( _
                strSource, strDestination, True)

Exit_RepairDatabase:

    RepairDatabase = lngRetVal
    Exit Function

Error_RepairDatabase:

    lngRetVal = cmpErrorOccurred
    MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, _
        "Error Information"

    Resume Exit_RepairDatabase

End Function



***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** 

Compact / Repair function below, but not advisable to do arbitrarily on every close - just replace/remove my on error code with your own

Function RepairDatabase(strSource As String, _
        strDestination As String) As Boolean
        ' Input values: the paths and file names of
        ' the source and destination files.

Dim strSource As String
Dim strDestination As String

strSource = "\\Dg\Debt \2010\Summary\Summary.mdb"
strDestination = "\\Dg\Debt \2010\Summary\Summary_Compact.mdb"

    ' Trap for errors.
    On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine

    ' Compact and repair the database. Use the return value of
    ' the CompactRepair method to determine if the file was
    ' successfully compacted.
    RepairDatabase = _
        Application.CompactRepair( _
        LogFile:=True, _
        SourceFile:=strSource, _
        DestinationFile:=strDestination)

    ' Reset the error trap and exit the function.
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

' Return False if an error occurs.
Exit_Function:
    Exit Function
ErrorRoutine:
    RepairDatabase = False
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".RepairDatabase", , True)
    Resume Exit_Function
End Function

Call the function as such:
Call RepairDatabase(strSource, strDestination)

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
I don’t think you can run the compact/repair code in DB#2, which is the DB that I want to do the operation on.  So, in DB#1, I tried this behind a Form:

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call RepairDatabase(strSource, strDestination)
End Sub

I put this in a module:
'Compact & Repair
Function RepairDatabase(strSource As String, strDestination As String) As Boolean
Dim strSource As String
Dim strDestination As String

strSource = "\\Dg\Debt \2010\Summary\Summary.mdb"
strDestination = "\\Dg\Debt \2010\Summary\Summary_Compact.mdb"

    ' Trap for errors.
    On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine

    ' Compact and repair the database. Use the return value of
    ' the CompactRepair method to determine if the file was
    ' successfully compacted.
    RepairDatabase = _
        Application.CompactRepair( _
        LogFile:=True, _
        SourceFile:=strSource, _
        DestinationFile:=strDestination)

    ' Reset the error trap and exit the function.
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

' Return False if an error occurs.

Exit_Function:
    Exit Function
ErrorRoutine:
    RepairDatabase = False
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".RepairDatabase", , True)
    Resume Exit_Function

End Function
```

Here is a good resource for you to read through when you have time.

http://www.databasedev.co.uk/compacting-and-repairing-ms-access.html